# Can I put a 700 x 35 tire on a Cannondale Quick 2 that has a 700 x 28 tire?

Tags: tire, compatibility, size

I usually ride roads with my 700 x 28 tire, but want to do a trail that has a multitude of surfaces.  So can I put a 700 x 35 on this bike?

Comment: If it fits.  If not, no.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately manufacturers tend not to publish max tire sizes, and ties of nominally the same width can vary quite a bit in actual width.

Checking the Cannondale web site shows that the Quick 2 model comes with nominally 30mm tires as standard. You can probably go up to 32mm with no problems but there may not be clearance for 35mm.

The place with the least tire clearance is typically between the chainstays. Measure the installed width of your 28mm tires and see of there is an additional 2.5 or 3.5 mm or clearance between the tires and frame.

You can also consider running a lower tire pressure on poor surfaces for better comfort and traction.

Comment: *Unfortunately manufacturers tend not to publish max tire sizes*. Fortunately though, this is changing and now many road bikes _brag_ about being able to fit up to 700c x 45 mm OR 650b x 2.1" tires.

Comment: Problem for bike manufacturers is tire sizes from manufacturers vary widely for the same size specification - especially with MTB and knobs sticking out the sides.  A 2.1"  can be wider than a 2.25"

Comment: Rim width also plays a big role, but that's not the point. The point is that more and more, you can get a feel for how large of tires you can fit in frames @mattnz

Answer (score 1):

In the 360° pictures – at least of the 2019 model – it looks like a lot of clearance between tires and frame/fork. A 35mm tire should fit easily.

Apparently the rims have 15mm of internal width which is a bit on the narrow side for a 35mm tire. At very low tire pressure the tire could “collapse” in turns and at very high pressures it could cause damage to the rims. If you use moderate pressures (let’s say 3 to 5bars) you should be alright though.

Comment: Rim width is an important consideration - I've damaged tyre side walls by running them on a too-narrow rim.